# Replace pixels in an image with another image

Tags: image

I want to replace the black pixel of (image 1) with another image so the result looks like image 2

Image 1

https://i.stack.imgur.com/WAQuz.jpg

Image 2 (result)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/k2Rs0.jpg

Is there a way to manage this with pref PHP or Javascript?

Comment: Please be more specific in your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, I am doing it with the commandline of Imagemagick, but there are PHP bindings available too. ImageMagick is installed in most Linux distors and available for Windows and OS X.

The command is this:

```
convert base.gif wallpaper.png -fx "u.r<0.1 && u.g<0.1 &&u.b<0.1? v : u" out.png
```

using your base image and some wallpaper from another question I answered.

Basically, the `-fx` operator allows you to do your own processing. So, I say if the red channel of the original image is less than 10% (i.e. really dark), and the green and the blue, replace the pixel with the corresponding pixel from the second image (wallpaper). The pixels of te first image are referrred to as `u` and those of the second image (wallpaper) as `v`. So `u.r` refers to the red component of the first image's pixels.

[image]

You can get a little fancier and avoid outliers and lonely pixels like under the fridge door and at the bottom left of the back wall on the carpet. Here I introduce a third image into the processing that is a copy of the original, but I then threshold it and median filter to reduce outliers. The first line of the command corresponds to the base image, the second line refers to the filtered base image and the third to the wallpaper. I now refer to the pixels of the base image as `u[0]`, those of the filtered base image as `u[1]` and those of the wallpaper as `u[2]`.

```
convert base.gif                                     \
   \( base.gif -depth 8 -threshold 1 -median 3x3 \)  \
   wallpaper.png                                     \
   -fx "u[1].r==0.0 ? u[2]:u[0]"                     \
   out.png
```

You may find the `-fx` operator slow if you have lots of images to do, so you could proceed like this instead. First make a nice mask of the black areas by thresholding and median filtering to remove outliers.

```
convert base.gif -depth 8 -threshold 1 -median 3x3 -negate mask.png
```

[image]

Now take the wallpaper and mask its opacity with the mask, then composite the result over the base image:

```
convert wallpaper.png                   \
        mask.png                        \
       -compose copyopacity -composite  \
        base.gif                        \ 
       -compose dstover -composite      \
        result.png
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for this answer but could you help me with the PHP conversion? I use the following code

exec('C:/Program Files/ImageMagick-6.9.0-Q16/convert Naamloos-1.gif naamloos.jpg -fx "u.r<0.1 && u.g<0.1 &&u.b<0.1? v : u" out.png');

<img src="out.png">

But it won't work

Comment: What is the error message? And can you get it to work at the command prompt (outside of PHP)?

Comment: You may have to put a full path in front of all your filenames. You also seem to have 2 input files - a `GIF` and a `JPEG`.

Comment: Thanks, it works now, turned out it was a typo in the filename ^^

Thanks alot for your help

Comment: Excellent! Glad to be of assistance. You will find the last version is signifcantly faster, if speed is important.